# How to set column height to include full window and all content using angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

How can I set the height of a column to be the height of the window and all of it's containing content. I've tried a bunch of solutions (css, jquery, javascript) but none of them seem to work for me.

The current result: the column takes up the height of the window but the background color is cut off when scrolling past the window.

Expected result: the column fills the height of the full window so that when I scroll the background color remains full extended to the bottom of the window.

I made a plnkr to show the current setup (note the background color does not flow past the window height): http://plnkr.co/edit/N9obSNozCC8WNyTA1Fqo?p=preview

```
//using a directive
.directive('fullHeight', function($window) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
          function setHeight() {
            var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
            $('.col').css('height', windowHeight);
          }
          setHeight();

          $(window).resize(function() {
            setHeight();
          });
        }
      };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the scrollHeight instead of the clientheight

```
var windowHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
```

You may need to adjust the value to accommodate the height of your header in this case though.

Comment: This does seem to work but it creates a longer and longer scroll area every time the window is resized. I update the plunk with your code.